# uploading codeigniter project as subdomain of server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have seen similar questions like this and I tried answers to of all them but they are not working so I am forced to ask this question sorry for that

I am trying to upload a codeigniter-based project to the server but I get a 404 page not found error displaying but I can see the fav icon

latest htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

The first few lines of config .php are

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| WARNING: You MUST set this value!
|
| If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try to guess the protocol and path
| your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set
| to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
| The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
| development and MUST NOT be used in production!
|
| If you need to allow multiple domains, remember that this file is still
| a PHP script and you can easily do that on your own.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://demos.ededge.in/';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

i uploaded it to a folder named demos

Comment: First check controller class name should start with capital letter.

Comment: Your server is Linux ?

Comment: which may i change filename or class name

Comment: i checked controller class name ewhich is in capital letter

Comment: Filename also in capital letter.

Comment: ok try let me try

Comment: it worked how can i mark

Comment: I will update this into answer then you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1) Controller class name should start with capital.

2) Filename name should start with capital.

Because Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: now i get error Access denied for user 'ededgein_ededge'@'198.134.120.4' (using password: YES)

Comment: Check your config file and match your credentials with server.

Answer (score 0):

Basic setup process:

1) First of all you need to point your sub-domain to specific folder path on hosting server.

2) Upload code to pointed sub-domain folder path.

3) Check folder and file owner group and permission. Folder permission 755 and File permission to 644.

4) Create database and import the database SQL file.

5) Configure BASE_URL in /application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://sub-domain.domain.com/';
```

6) Change encryption key in config file

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'to_any_16_character_alpha_numeric_special_character';
```

NOTE: Do not use "$" in key. PHP consider as a variable.

7) Configure database connection in /application/config/database.php

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "database_hostname";
$db['default']['username'] = "database_username";
$db['default']['password'] = "database_password";
$db['default']['database'] = "database_name";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'database_driver';
```

NOTE: 
- You need to assign database user with proper rights in created database.
- Select proper database driver name like "mysqli".

8) Check .htaccess code if you don't want index.php in URL. Basic .htaccess code for rewrite module

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```